# How to replace characters in a text by space except for list of words in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace all characters in a text by spaces, but I want to leave a list of words.

For instante:

```
text = "John Thomas bought 300 shares of Acme Corp. in 2006."
list_of_words = ['Acme Corp.', 'John Thomas']
```

My wanted output would be:

```
output_text = "***********                      **********         "
```

I would like to change unwanted characters to spaces before I do the * replacement:

`"John Thomas                      Acme Corp.         "`

Right know I know how to replace only the list of words, but cannot come out with the spaces part.

```
rep = {key: len(key)*'_**_' for key in list_of_words}
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.items()) 
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], text)
```

Comment: The dictionary should be like this `rep = {key: len(key)**' for key in list_of_words}`

Comment: If you can assume that `*` is forbidden in the original sentence, then replace each non `*` to space after the first replacement.

Comment: Hi, have you had time to try my suggestion below?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks you for your prompt reply last time. I am trying to implement your procedure but instead of sub the pattern with a character ('*') I want to replace the pattern by a mapping from a dictionary. For instance:

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "John Thomas bought 300 shares of Acme Corp. in 2006." by "11111111111                      2222222222         " where dictionary_of_classes={'name': '1', 'corp': '2', ...}, and we know the mapping between list_of_words and the dictionary_of_classes. I am trying to figure out how to make this correspondence in the lambda function inside pattern.sub(). Any help?

Comment: Looks like a new question.

Comment: No, it’s actually solvable with your solution without * replacement. Done. Thanks @Wiktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build a pattern like

```
(?s)word1|word2|wordN|(.)
```

When Group 1 matches, replace with a space, else, replace with the same amount of asterisks as the match text length:

```
import re
text = "John Thomas bought 300 shares of Acme Corp. in 2006."
list_of_words = ['Acme Corp.', 'John Thomas']
pat = "|".join(sorted(map(re.escape, list_of_words), key=len, reverse=True))
pattern = re.compile(f'{pat}|(.)', re.S)
print(pattern.sub(lambda m: " " if m.group(1) else len(m.group(0))*"*", text))
=> '***********                      **********         '
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GvsK3F)

**Details**

- `sorted(map(re.escape, list_of_words), key=len, reverse=True)` - escapes words in `list_of_words` and sorts the list by length in descending order (it will be necessary if there are multiword items)
- `"|".join(...)` - build the alternatives out of `list_of_words` items
- `lambda m: " " if m.group(1) else len(m.group(0))*"*"` - if Group 1 matches, replace with a space, else with the asterisks of the same length as the match length.